# Return Statement Missing

Tags: java

```
public boolean healthy()
   {

      if(organic)
      {

         if(toppings<=3)
         {
            if((size=="small"))
            {
               return true;

            }
            else
            {
               return false;
            }
         }
      }

      else
      {
      return false;
      }

   }
```

The program is saying that I am missing a return statement before the last bracket. But if I were to put one there, there would always be one answer to the boolean which would be true and false. This puts all the other 'if' statements to no use which is a problem. Any help?

Comment: true or false** not both

Comment: what if `toppings<=3` is false

Comment: As @FastSnail Says.. thats where ure missing ur return statement..

Comment: [Don't use `==` for string comparison in Java.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: No, I figured it out, Fast Snail was right except I just had to add an extra false statement inside of the toppings bracket. Thank anyways.

Answer (score 4):

Help put an end to bad code

```
public boolean healthy() {
  return (organic && toppings <= 3 && size === "small");
}
```

Your code had no `else` branch on `toppigs <= 3` which could result in no value being returned.

Also, never write stuff like this

```
if (something < 2) { 
  return true;
}
else {
  return false;
}
```

Instead, just write

```
return something < 2;
```

Comment: Like a breath of fresh air. Well... besides for the parentheses, but I'm not one to nitpick *(who am I kidding?)*

Comment: The parentheses are optional yes, but I think they could help just a bit with the readability of the long logic chain. Completely optional, take 'em or leave 'em ^_^.

Comment: Oh and this is `java`, not `javascript`, so `size.equals("small")`.

Comment: I already fixed it based on how I did it. Everything worked, but there was one small thing I had to add.